# Different Homepages based on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm starting a new site for a client. They have different user roles depending on what account you sign into on their site. Some users will see all options others won't. Some will see options that other accounts can't and vice versa. I was wondering if I will need a separate view-page made for each type of account or if I could use one view-page but lock specific people out from seeing specific things on their page. If able to do either way what would be the easier/recommended of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use second variant, cuz support a few page very hard. So if you chose second variant  you just use `@if(isAdmin){one html}` `else {other html}` in your view page.

Comment: Okay I'll try this. Thank you for helping. I'm a student doing a work term and everything my job entails I will learn next semester haha. Any and all help is welcome